# Browser Back Button Not working Properly in Lightning for Vf Pages?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visualforce-in-lightning

Actually my vf page has links to another vf page. Whenever i navigate from one Vf Page to other Vf Page Using these links browser back button Doesn't work Properly. It goes Back to last selected lightning tabs.

I have searched for this Issue and Found out this Link.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BefQAE

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround that whenever i am navigating in Visualforce, i am using following js method.

```
function redirectTo(url,retURL){

        if(typeof sforce !='undefined' && sforce.one) {
            var stateObj = { };
           var currentUrl = window.location.href;
            history.pushState(stateObj, null, currentUrl);
           sforce.one.navigateToURL(url,true);
       }
       else {
          window.location.href = url+'?retURL='+retURL;
       }
     }
```

Is there any other way to handle this problem.