# Navigation from lwc inside a visual force page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation, ltngoutapp

I have overridden a standard salesforce button with Visualforce page. I am using a lwc component inside it using `ltng:out`. Then from lightning component I want to navigate to some other page but I am not able to do so.
In aura I used to use `sforce.one.navigatetourl` for similar situation.
[Browser Back Button Not working Properly in Lightning for Vf Pages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155073/browser-back-button-not-working-properly-in-lightning-for-vf-pages)

If I use `window.location` then I get this window inside window UI. [image]

How to safely navigate back to salesforce lightning ui from here.
I have used lightning navigation that doesn't work inside ltng:out.

Code is pretty simple:

```html
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:accountDelete" />
</aura:application>
```

cmp.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-button label="goThere" onclick={handleNavigation}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

cmp.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire  } from 'lwc';
    handleNavigation(){
        window.location = '/001';
    }
```

Visualforce page:

```html
<apex:page standardController="Account"  sidebar="false">
<apex:includeLightning />    
<div id="LightningComponentid" />    
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:AccountDeleteApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:accountDelete",
            { 
            "id" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
            },
            "LightningComponentid",
            function(cmp) {});
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution passing function as attribute in lwc.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"  sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <div id="LightningComponentid" />    
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:AccountDeleteApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:accountDelete",
          { 
            "id" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}",
            "navigateToList" : navigateToList
          },
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {});
    });
    function navigateToList(url) {
      if(typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one){
         sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
      } else {
         window.location.href = url;
      }
    }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Then make changes in LWC

```
import { LightningElement, api  } from 'lwc';
export default class AccountSetDelete extends LightningElement {
    @api id;
    @api navigateToList;
    handleNavigation(){
       this.navigateToList('/001');
    }
}
```

So solution is pass a function reference from vf page to lwc and then call that method from lwc and use

> sforce.one.navigateToURL

in vf pages.

Comment: I was quite close to the answer with similar idea, glad that you found the solution. For supporting the VF page in classic, you could use idea from Erik's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/147558/4726) which checks if the page is in lightning, uses sforce navigation otherwise window navigation.

Comment: thanks @Raul. Updated code to support classic and lightning.